# How to debug an Android (Application Not Responding) crash written using Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, debugging

I have written my first app for Android with Qt and some ANR reports has been received. (They all look like the code at the end).

From the output I can see that the problem is probably related to the function:

```
QResource::registerResource()
```

but I do not get any more information than this from the trace. I am also unable to reproduce the ANR on any of my devices, but I do not have any of the devices the ANR is reported on.

The only idea I have so far for why the app might crash is that registerResource() function might be slow and blocking (running in GUI thread) and therefor the application might crash?

Anything else I can try to debug this problem?

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/jactiveltexx/jactivelte:5.0.1/LRX22C/I9295XXUDOB4:user/release-keys'
Revision: '16'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 23341, tid: 23365, name: QtThread  >>> no.myApp.www <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    r0 00000000  r1 00005b45  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
    r4 ad7ffdb8  r5 00000006  r6 0000000c  r7 0000010c
    r8 ad7fee30  r9 275951ac  sl ad7fee6c  fp ad7fecf4
    ip 00005b45  sp ad7fec88  lr b6f68fc5  pc b6f8c910  cpsr 600f0010

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00037910  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01 pc 00013fc1  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
    #02 pc 00014bdf  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03 pc 00011521  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
    #04 pc 0000fcac  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05 pc 00050810  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libgnustl_shared.so (__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()+348)
    #06 pc 0004e6e0  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libgnustl_shared.so (__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())+8)
    #07 pc 0004e780  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libgnustl_shared.so (std::terminate()+12)
    #08 pc 0004eacc  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libgnustl_shared.so (__cxa_throw+156)
    #09 pc 0004f0a8  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libgnustl_shared.so (operator new(unsigned int)+108)
    #10 pc 0004f11c  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libgnustl_shared.so (operator new[](unsigned int)+4)
    #11 pc 00123179  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libQt5Core.so
    #12 pc 001233d7  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libQt5Core.so (QResource::registerResource(QString const&, QString const&)+350)
    #13 pc 000044ed  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libmyApp.so (DeviceAndroid::loadExpansionFile(unsigned int)+640)
    #14 pc 00004925  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libmyApp.so
    #15 pc 00004a43  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libmyApp.so (DeviceAndroid::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)+30)
    #16 pc 00189e69  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libQt5Core.so (QMetaObject::metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)+44)
    #17 pc 0013413f  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libQt5Qml.so
    #18 pc 000fffcb  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libQt5Qml.so
    #19 pc 001002a1  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libQt5Qml.so
    #20 pc 00100533  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libQt5Qml.so (QV4::QObjectMethod::callInternal(QV4::CallData*)+574)
    #21 pc 000d0e09  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libQt5Qml.so
    #22 pc 00108c0f  /data/app/no.myApp.www-1/lib/arm/libQt5Qml.so (QV4::Runtime::callProperty(QV4::ExecutionEngine*, int, QV4::CallData*)+366)
    #23 pc 00008221  <unknown>
```

Comment: Looks like `new` is throwing, which happens when allocation fails, maybe these devices are running out of memory on app startup.

Comment: @user657267: That might be the problem. The expansion file is huge (500MB+) and if the registerResource() function loads it all to memory I guess that could be it. Still a little strange as the crash is reported on several high end mobile phones compared to some of the phones I have tested with.

Comment: @user657267: Since _new_ is throwing I assume the heap memory the app has access to is too small?

Comment: You can't really assume anything when `new` throws but more often than not it's because memory is exhausted (i.e. the OS refuses to allocate any more).